# How to set token transaction limit?

Tags: tokens, pancakeswap, liquidity-provider

If I create a token on Cointool.app, is there any way I can add a limit on the number of tokens bought in any transaction? Or does it depend on the amount that's in the liquidity? e.g. If I want to make it that no one can buy more than 1 trillion tokens at any one time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Answer

From what I have seen about cointool, **no**. Because for that, you would have to update the code in the ERC20 token contract they generated for you (see second section of this answer) and it *seems* cointool deploys directly without letting you update the code.

## Kind of off topic element

The only way I can imagine to limit the number of token bought (aka *transfer* from the point of view of the contract (correct me if wrong)) is to implement a bit of logic yourself in the `transfer` function.

Something like:

if token_to_transfer > transfer_limit
then revert (or whatever is the way now, have not developped in solidity for a while)

Answer (score -1):

You can check your Gas limit page... settings inside....

Comment: Its not eth, its a bep20 token. On pancakeswap

Comment: You should add some details. This answer is too succint.